# Multiple instances of code work perfectly in PHP 5.2.13 but not in PHP 5.4.6

Tags: php

I have a number of PHP websites that are right now working perfectly fine running on PHP 5.2.13.  But when I copy the code to my local development server running PHP 5.4.6 the lots of different pieces of code break with errors...

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in jobadd.php on line 1604

or

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in jobadd.php on line 236

It seams the common suggestion is having \<\? instead of \<\?php but all the pieces of code are free of these things and all the open brackets have matching closed brackets.  I'm assuming something has changed between 5.2 and 5.4 but I can't find it when I search for it and to my discerning eye the code is correct.  I don't want to include a portion of the code as they are all significantly large and unwieldy if I can find a small portion that errors I will post it.  Another possibility is that there is a missing or superfluous semi-colon, but again to my eye everything checks out.

Has anyone else come across something like this?  If I ever upgrade our production server are we going to have to rewrite a lot of our code because of something inconsequential.

The last thought is that 5.4 is more strict about syntax than 5.2 was I am seeing a lot of mistakes is the HTML code just not the PHP code.

Thanks everyone please let me know if you have any insights in to this.
Russ

```
<?php
/*
 * Created on 12/03/2012 4:12:27 PM , by richard
 *
 * mybidswap
 *
 */
?>

<h3>Categories</h3>

<table class="category-list">
<tbody>
<?php

$counter = 1;

foreach($category_list as $row)
{ ?>
        <?php if($counter == 1){ ?><tr><? } ?>
                <td>
                <a href='<?php echo base_url('auctions/?category_id='.$row['auction_category_id']); ?>'>
                <img width="80" height="80" src="<?php echo base_url() . 'images/category-images/'. $row['category_image']; ?>" /><br />
                        <span><?php echo $row['category_title']; ?></span>
            </a>
                </td>
        <?php if($counter == 5){ ?><tr><? } ?>
    <?php $counter++; if($counter >= 5){ $counter = 1; } ?>
<?php }
?>
<tbody>
</table>
<?php //new dBug($category_list); ?>
```

This is a small snippet of code that produces an error....

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in category_list.php on line 33

```
PHP Version 5.3.16


System  Linux compaqqy-RHEL.329ncle.stockhammer.id.au 2.6.18-194.el5 #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 21:52:43 EDT 2010 i686
Build Date  Aug 21 2012 16:08:12
Configure Command    './configure' '--with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql' '--with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config' '--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs' '--enable-zip' '--with-mcrypt=/usr/local/bin/mcrypt' '--with-zlib-dir' '--enable-mbstring'
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support   disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API 20090626
PHP Extension   20090626
Zend Extension  220090626
Zend Extension Build    API220090626,NTS
PHP Extension Build API20090626,NTS
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   disabled
Zend Memory Manager enabled
Zend Multibyte Support  disabled
IPv6 Support    enabled
Registered PHP Streams  compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports tcp, udp, unix, udg
Registered Stream Filters   zlib.*, convert.iconv.*, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

PHP Credits

Configuration

apache2handler

Apache Version  Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.3.16
Apache API Version  20051115
Server Administrator    russgrue@localhost
Hostname:Port   devel.mybidswap.com:0
User/Group  apache(48)/48
Max Requests    Per Child: 10000 - Keep Alive: on - Max Per Connection: 100
Timeouts    Connection: 300 - Keep-Alive: 5
Virtual Server  Yes
Server Root /usr/local/apache2
Loaded Modules  core mod_authn_file mod_authn_default mod_authz_host mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_user mod_authz_default mod_auth_basic mod_include mod_filter mod_log_config mod_env mod_setenvif mod_version prefork http_core mod_mime mod_status mod_autoindex mod_asis mod_info mod_cgi mod_negotiation mod_dir mod_actions mod_userdir mod_alias mod_rewrite mod_so mod_php5

Directive   Local Value Master Value
engine  1   1
last_modified   0   0
xbithack    0   0

Apache Environment

Variable    Value
HTTP_HOST   devel.mybidswap.com
HTTP_CONNECTION keep-alive
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.79 Safari/537.1
HTTP_ACCEPT text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    gzip,deflate,sdch
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
HTTP_COOKIE cisession=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22100bfd166f29043305c35bfd7a1a9a39%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A11%3A%22192.168.0.7%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A106%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.1+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F21.0.1180.79+Safari%2F537.1%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1345530365%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7D42f2217d5511a7cd57955aceddb30f42; __unam=80130ed-13942c61c34-58d4de10-8
HTTP_DNT    1
PATH    /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
SERVER_SIGNATURE    no value
SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.3.16
SERVER_NAME devel.mybidswap.com
SERVER_ADDR 192.168.0.49
SERVER_PORT 80
REMOTE_ADDR 192.168.0.7
DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/russgrue/Russell/ftp.mybidswap.com/www.mybidswap.com/web/content
SERVER_ADMIN    russgrue@localhost
SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/russgrue/Russell/ftp.mybidswap.com/www.mybidswap.com/web/content/blah.php
REMOTE_PORT 61997
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
QUERY_STRING    no value
REQUEST_URI /blah.php
SCRIPT_NAME /blah.php

HTTP Headers Information

HTTP Request Headers
HTTP Request    GET /blah.php HTTP/1.1
Host    devel.mybidswap.com
Connection  keep-alive
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.79 Safari/537.1
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie  cisession=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22100bfd166f29043305c35bfd7a1a9a39%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A11%3A%22192.168.0.7%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A106%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.1+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F21.0.1180.79+Safari%2F537.1%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1345530365%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7D42f2217d5511a7cd57955aceddb30f42; __unam=80130ed-13942c61c34-58d4de10-8
DNT 1
HTTP Response Headers
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.16
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100
Connection  Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Content-Type    text/html

Core

PHP Version 5.3.16

Directive   Local Value Master Value
allow_call_time_pass_reference  On  On
allow_url_fopen On  On
allow_url_include   Off Off
always_populate_raw_post_data   Off Off
arg_separator.input &   &
arg_separator.output    &   &
asp_tags    Off Off
auto_append_file    no value    no value
auto_globals_jit    On  On
auto_prepend_file   no value    no value
browscap    no value    no value
default_charset no value    no value
default_mimetype    text/html   text/html
define_syslog_variables Off Off
disable_classes no value    no value
disable_functions   no value    no value
display_errors  On  On
display_startup_errors  On  On
doc_root    no value    no value
docref_ext  no value    no value
docref_root no value    no value
enable_dl   Off Off
error_append_string no value    no value
error_log   no value    no value
error_prepend_string    no value    no value
error_reporting 30719   30719
exit_on_timeout Off Off
expose_php  On  On
extension_dir   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626 /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
file_uploads    On  On
highlight.bg    #FFFFFF #FFFFFF
highlight.comment   #FF8000 #FF8000
highlight.default   #0000BB #0000BB
highlight.html  #000000 #000000
highlight.keyword   #007700 #007700
highlight.string    #DD0000 #DD0000
html_errors On  On
ignore_repeated_errors  Off Off
ignore_repeated_source  Off Off
ignore_user_abort   Off Off
implicit_flush  Off Off
include_path    .:/usr/local/lib/php    .:/usr/local/lib/php
log_errors  On  On
log_errors_max_len  1024    1024
magic_quotes_gpc    On  On
magic_quotes_runtime    Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase Off Off
mail.add_x_header   On  On
mail.force_extra_parameters no value    no value
mail.log    no value    no value
max_execution_time  30  30
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  60  60
max_input_vars  1000    1000
memory_limit    128M    128M
open_basedir    no value    no value
output_buffering    4096    4096
output_handler  no value    no value
post_max_size   8M  8M
precision   14  14
realpath_cache_size 16K 16K
realpath_cache_ttl  120 120
register_argc_argv  Off Off
register_globals    Off Off
register_long_arrays    On  On
report_memleaks On  On
report_zend_debug   On  On
request_order   GP  GP
safe_mode   Off Off
safe_mode_exec_dir  /usr/local/php/bin  /usr/local/php/bin
safe_mode_gid   Off Off
safe_mode_include_dir   no value    no value
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i 
serialize_precision 17  17
short_open_tag  Off Off
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
sql.safe_mode   Off Off
track_errors    On  On
unserialize_callback_func   no value    no value
upload_max_filesize 2M  2M
upload_tmp_dir  no value    no value
user_dir    no value    no value
user_ini.cache_ttl  300 300
user_ini.filename   .user.ini   .user.ini
variables_order GPCS    GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number 0   0
xmlrpc_errors   Off Off
y2k_compliance  On  On
zend.enable_gc  On  On

ctype

ctype functions enabled

date

date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2012.3
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Australia/Sydney

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   Australia/Sydney    Australia/Sydney

dom

DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.6.26
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled

ereg

Regex Library   Bundled library enabled

fileinfo

fileinfo support    enabled
version 1.0.5-dev

filter

Input Validation and Filtering  enabled
Revision    $Id: 2b8c730d7dfaa8485d07cd792f0c82852ffe4113 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
filter.default  unsafe_raw  unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags    no value    no value

hash

hash support    enabled
Hashing Engines md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost adler32 crc32 crc32b salsa10 salsa20 haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5

iconv

iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    glibc
iconv library version   2.5

Directive   Local Value Master Value
iconv.input_encoding    ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding   ISO-8859-1  ISO-8859-1

json

json support    enabled
json version    1.2.1

libxml

libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version 2.6.26
libXML Loaded Version   20626
libXML streams  enabled

mbstring

Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation disabled

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

Multibyte (japanese) regex support  enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) backtrack check On
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version 4.7.1

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mbstring.detect_order   no value    no value
mbstring.encoding_translation   Off Off
mbstring.func_overload  0   0
mbstring.http_input pass    pass
mbstring.http_output    pass    pass
mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)
mbstring.internal_encoding  no value    no value
mbstring.language   neutral neutral
mbstring.strict_detection   Off Off
mbstring.substitute_character   no value    no value

mcrypt

mcrypt support  enabled
mcrypt_filter support   enabled
Version 2.5.8
Api No  20021217
Supported ciphers   cast-128 gost rijndael-128 twofish arcfour cast-256 loki97 rijndael-192 saferplus wake blowfish-compat des rijndael-256 serpent xtea blowfish enigma rc2 tripledes
Supported modes cbc cfb ctr ecb ncfb nofb ofb stream

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mcrypt.algorithms_dir   no value    no value
mcrypt.modes_dir    no value    no value

mysql

MySQL Support   enabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
Client API version  5.5.27
MYSQL_MODULE_TYPE   external
MYSQL_SOCKET    /tmp/mysql.sock
MYSQL_INCLUDE   -I/usr/local/mysql/include
MYSQL_LIBS  -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysql.allow_local_infile    On  On
mysql.allow_persistent  On  On
mysql.connect_timeout   60  60
mysql.default_host  no value    no value
mysql.default_password  no value    no value
mysql.default_port  no value    no value
mysql.default_socket    /tmp/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
mysql.default_user  no value    no value
mysql.max_links Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.max_persistent    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysql.trace_mode    Off Off

mysqli

MysqlI Support  enabled
Client API library version  5.5.27
Active Persistent Links 0
Inactive Persistent Links   0
Active Links    0
Client API header version   5.5.27
MYSQLI_SOCKET   /tmp/mysql.sock

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile   On  On
mysqli.allow_persistent On  On
mysqli.default_host no value    no value
mysqli.default_port 3306    3306
mysqli.default_pw   no value    no value
mysqli.default_socket   no value    no value
mysqli.default_user no value    no value
mysqli.max_links    Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent   Unlimited   Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect    Off Off

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support  enabled
PCRE Library Version    8.12 2011-01-15

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit    1000000 1000000
pcre.recursion_limit    100000  100000

PDO

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql, sqlite, sqlite2

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL    enabled
Client API version  5.5.27

Directive   Local Value Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket    /tmp/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock

pdo_sqlite

PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x   enabled
SQLite Library  3.7.7.1

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support   enabled
Phar EXT version    2.0.1
Phar API version    1.1.1
SVN revision    $Id: f7d08da4ab9e515975840c28b830edc9437c3026 $
Phar-based phar archives    enabled
Tar-based phar archives enabled
ZIP-based phar archives enabled
gzip compression    enabled
bzip2 compression   disabled (install pecl/bz2)
OpenSSL support disabled (install ext/openssl)

Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.

Directive   Local Value Master Value
phar.cache_list no value    no value
phar.readonly   On  On
phar.require_hash   On  On

posix

Revision    $Id: c00b7465003bf16b27764ccaea3c159ca2e4419d $

Reflection

Reflection  enabled
Version $Id: 23c90449811cd1a9c860b115456b64946c2823a9 $

session

Session Support enabled
Registered save handlers    files user sqlite
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   no value    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0

SimpleXML

Simplexml support   enabled
Revision    $Id: a379111021e24ef020a2eefd8ca830cb1ab5b280 $
Schema support  enabled

SPL

SPL support enabled
Interfaces  Countable, OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

SQLite

SQLite support  enabled
PECL Module version 2.0-dev $Id$
SQLite Library  2.8.17
SQLite Encoding iso8859

Directive   Local Value Master Value
sqlite.assoc_case   0   0

sqlite3

SQLite3 support enabled
SQLite3 module version  0.7-dev
SQLite Library  3.7.7.1

Directive   Local Value Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir   no value    no value

standard

Dynamic Library Support enabled
Path to sendmail    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Directive   Local Value Master Value
assert.active   1   1
assert.bail 0   0
assert.callback no value    no value
assert.quiet_eval   0   0
assert.warning  1   1
auto_detect_line_endings    0   0
default_socket_timeout  60  60
from    no value    no value
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars  PHP_    PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars    LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH
url_rewriter.tags   a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent  no value    no value

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support   enabled

xml

XML Support active
XML Namespace Support   active
libxml2 Version 2.6.26

xmlreader

XMLReader   enabled

xmlwriter

XMLWriter   enabled

zip

Zip enabled
Extension Version   $Id$
Zip version 1.11.0
Libzip version  0.10.1

zlib

ZLib Support    enabled
Stream Wrapper support  compress.zlib://
Stream Filter support   zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version    1.2.3
Linked Version  1.2.3

Directive   Local Value Master Value
zlib.output_compression Off Off
zlib.output_compression_level   -1  -1
zlib.output_handler no value    no value

Additional Modules

Module Name

Environment

Variable    Value
SSH_AGENT_PID   31828
HOSTNAME    compaqqy-RHEL.329ncle.stockhammer.id.au
DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID  no value
TERM    xterm
SHELL   /bin/bash
HISTSIZE    1000
GTK_RC_FILES    /etc/gtk/gtkrc:/root/.gtkrc-1.2-gnome2
WINDOWID    26214480
USER    root
LS_COLORS   no=00:fi=00:di=00;34:ln=00;36:pi=40;33:so=00;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:ex=00;32:*.cmd=00;32:*.exe=00;32:*.com=00;32:*.btm=00;32:*.bat=00;32:*.sh=00;32:*.csh=00;32:*.tar=00;31:*.tgz=00;31:*.arj=00;31:*.taz=00;31:*.lzh=00;31:*.zip=00;31:*.z=00;31:*.Z=00;31:*.gz=00;31:*.bz2=00;31:*.bz=00;31:*.tz=00;31:*.rpm=00;31:*.cpio=00;31:*.jpg=00;35:*.gif=00;35:*.bmp=00;35:*.xbm=00;35:*.xpm=00;35:*.png=00;35:*.tif=00;35:
GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET    /tmp/keyring-WzhlY3/socket
SSH_AUTH_SOCK   /tmp/ssh-jbDMk31792/agent.31792
SESSION_MANAGER local/compaqqy-RHEL.329ncle.stockhammer.id.au:/tmp/.ICE-unix/31792
MAIL    /var/spool/mail/root
PATH    /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESKTOP_SESSION default
GDM_XSERVER_LOCATION    local
INPUTRC /etc/inputrc
PWD /root/Desktop/php-5.3.16
XMODIFIERS  @im=none
LANG    C
TZ  Australia/Sydney
GDMSESSION  default
SSH_ASKPASS /usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
SHLVL   4
HOME    /root
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID    Default
LOGNAME root
CVS_RSH ssh
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS    unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-LCFkaQTgCp,guid=88ef7f0ee5b5852e6c41fb0050332257
LESSOPEN    |/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
DISPLAY :0.0
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES  1
COLORTERM   gnome-terminal
XAUTHORITY  /tmp/.gdmVH8EJW
_   /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd

PHP Variables

Variable    Value
_COOKIE["cisession"]    a:5:{s:10:\"session_id\";s:32:\"100bfd166f29043305c35bfd7a1a9a39\";s:10:\"ip_address\";s:11:\"192.168.0.7\";s:10:\"user_agent\";s:106:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.79 Safari/537.1\";s:13:\"last_activity\";i:1345530365;s:9:\"user_data\";s:0:\"\";}42f2217d5511a7cd57955aceddb30f42
_COOKIE["__unam"]   80130ed-13942c61c34-58d4de10-8
_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]    devel.mybidswap.com
_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]  keep-alive
_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.79 Safari/537.1
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"] gzip,deflate,sdch
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"] en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET"]  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
_SERVER["HTTP_COOKIE"]  cisession=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22100bfd166f29043305c35bfd7a1a9a39%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A11%3A%22192.168.0.7%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A106%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+6.1%3B+WOW64%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.1+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F21.0.1180.79+Safari%2F537.1%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1345530365%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7D42f2217d5511a7cd57955aceddb30f42; __unam=80130ed-13942c61c34-58d4de10-8
_SERVER["HTTP_DNT"] 1
_SERVER["PATH"] /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"] no value
_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]  Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) PHP/5.3.16
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  devel.mybidswap.com
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  192.168.0.49
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]  192.168.0.7
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /home/russgrue/Russell/ftp.mybidswap.com/www.mybidswap.com/web/content
_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"] russgrue@localhost
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  /home/russgrue/Russell/ftp.mybidswap.com/www.mybidswap.com/web/content/blah.php
_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]  61997
_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]    CGI/1.1
_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]  HTTP/1.1
_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]   GET
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] no value
_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]  /blah.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /blah.php
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] /blah.php
_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"] 1345530517

PHP License

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group and included in the distribution in the file: LICENSE

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.


ABOVE is the output from phpinfo()...   Please note that I down graded the version of PHP to 5.3.16 as this is the version our production server is getting upgraded to in the next few days (I wasn't told this until just now).
```

Comment: i would not expect a "syntax error" when changing php version, are you sure no errors have been made in the copying

Comment: For our benefit and yours, you could try (as an exercise) to systematically slim down a file until it is very small and still producing the error. For one, you may run into the solution just by doing this, and for two you will have a reasonable chunk to post here so we might help.

Answer (score 2):

I sused it...   In each of the effected files there is a shorthand \<\? not a full \<\?php.

I thought that the change over happened between PHP 4.x and 5.x so I while I did look for them as a long of references talked about them, I didn't check every single one and there was a least one sneaky one in a hard to see spot that was compounded because the code isn't very clean.

So thanks everyone for your helpful answers and comments!!!  We can write this one off as resolved.

Thanks
Russ

Answer (score 0):

5.2 is just as strict when it comes to syntax, might just be your "local server" configuration have you tried to put your code on another production server ( i have made the switch and there was nothing that went haywire with my code)

Comment: I am about to try the code in a new vhost on the same server but we don't have any other production servers to try it on.